# name 'urlpatterns' is not defined when doing translation (+= i18n_patterns)

Tags: django, url-pattern, language-translation

I want to add a language prefix in URL patterns just like the django documentation homepage. Following this [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns) my `urls.py` looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin

from myapp import views
from myapp.views import MyFirstView, MySecondView

myapp_patterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.CategoryView, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$', MyFirstView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/mysecond_view/$', MySecondView, name='mysecond_view')
]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^categories/', include(myapp_patterns)),
    url(r'^', views.LandingView),
]
```

This works but now when I add `+= i18n_patterns`

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^categories/', include(myapp_patterns)),
    url(r'^', views.LandingView),
]
```

I get the error: NameError: name 'urlpatterns' is not defined

I did add the `LocalMiddleware`:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

as well as this:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

I don't understand how `urlpatterns` all of the sudden is not defined anymore. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried `i18n_patterns(..)` instead of `i18n_patterns [..]`?

Comment: yes, I tried that, too, didn't change anything

Comment: `urlpatterns += i18n_patterns  ` should be `urlpatterns= i18n_patterns  `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primarily because of `+=`. There's no previous definition of `urlpatterns`.

You should start of with assignment `=` to define it.