# NameError: name 'urlpatterns' is not defined using i18n_patterns

Tags: python, django

I have problems writing the urls for translation. According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401238/name-urlpatterns-is-not-defined-when-doing-translation-i18n-patterns) I understand that it is because I have += so I need to put this = the bad thing is that I have to translate all my urls I can't leave any outside of i18n, what can I do to include all my urls there?

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

app_name='Clientes'


urlpatterns+= i18n_patterns(
    path('',views.list_clientes,name='clientes_list'),
    path('add',views.create_clientes.as_view(),name='clientes_add'),
    path('edit/<int:pk>',views.edit_clientes.as_view(),name='clientes_edit'),
    path('<int:pk>/',views.detail_clientes.as_view(),name='clientes_detail'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>',views.eliminar_cliente.as_view(),name='clientes_delete'),
)
```

Comment: You didn't define `urlpatterns` before you tried to add to it

Comment: yes in fact I understand that I have to put this urlpatterns=[] and then this urlpatterns+= i18n_patterns()

the problem is that all my urls need to be translated, that is, I need this urlpatterns+= i18n_patterns()

Comment: @AnaidBracho: you misunderstood the answer. It defined a list, and then `+=` exactly because *not* all url patterns are translated there. But if all patterns should be translated, you assign the result of `i18n_patterns(..)` to the `urlpatterns`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define `urlpatterns` before. If you want to translate all paths, you use:

```
#           🖟 assignment
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('',views.list_clientes,name='clientes_list'),
    path('add',views.create_clientes.as_view(),name='clientes_add'),
    path('edit/<int:pk>',views.edit_clientes.as_view(),name='clientes_edit'),
    path('<int:pk>/',views.detail_clientes.as_view(),name='clientes_detail'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>',views.eliminar_cliente.as_view(),name='clientes_delete'),
)
```

In the linked answer, it first defines a list, and then extends it with `+=`, exactly because *not* all url patterns are translated there. But if all patterns should be translated, you assign the result of `i18n_patterns(..)` to the `urlpatterns`.